# ExtJS - how do you access values from the constructor when you define a class?

Tags: javascript, extjs, constructor

Looking for some help here. As you can see below for the combobox xtype I am trying to populate this from the typeStore but I'm not sure how I can access values in the constructor the way my code is currently laid out. Is this possible?

Also, the field names 'name' and 'email' - I am trying to populate them by setting params on the config (but again, I can't seem to access this from this section of my code). Normally I would've thought it could be access by something like 'this.config.params' but I'm really not sure how to access this as it's out of scope I believe.

```
Ext.define('school',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'school',
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    items:
        [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'name',
                //value: (?),
                allowBlank:false,
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                //value: (?),
                allowBlank:false,
                vtype: 'email'
            },
            {
                xtype:'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Type',
                name: 'types',
                //store: typeStore,
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'type',
                valueField: 'typeid',
                multiSelect: true,
                emptyText: 'Select type',
                editable: false
            },
```

```
    constructor: function(config)
    {

        let me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.initConfig(config);

        let typeStore= new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'TypesManager',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items',
                    idProperty: 'typeid'
                }
            },
            fields: ['typeid', 'typename'],
            autoLoad: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just putting store config in combobox?

Comment: @ŽeljkoMitrović sorry if this is really obvious (very new to extjs), but how would I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

which version of ExtJs are you using ?

If it is >= 5, you should have a ViewModel, linked to your view. In that viewModel, you would declare the store you need for your combo, and the data you want to put as value of your textfields.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('school',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'school',
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    items:
        [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'name',
                //value: (?),
                allowBlank:false,
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                //value: (?),
                allowBlank:false,
                vtype: 'email'
            },
            {
                xtype:'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Type',
                name: 'types',
                store: {
                   proxy: {
                       type: 'ajax',
                       url: 'TypesManager',
                       reader: {
                           type: 'json',
                           root: 'items',
                           idProperty: 'typeid'
                       }
                   },
                   fields: ['typeid', 'typename'],
                   autoLoad: true
               },
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'type',
                valueField: 'typeid',
                multiSelect: true,
                emptyText: 'Select type',
                editable: false
            },
```

Comment: thanks this works! Out of interest, if I created the store in my constructor, would it still be possible to use it the way I initially intended (ie. in my combobox something like 'store: typeStore')?

Comment: not the way you imagine. You would have to find correct child using down selector and then set store to it. Or you could define global store and the use it's id. If you are using more recent versions of ExtJS you might check out their MVVM architecture. It is much easier to work with it as Models Views and Controllers are separated